# pandas unique values how to iterate as a starting point

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stock

Good Morning, (bad beginner)

I have the following pandas dataframe:

[image]

My goal is to take the firs time a new ID appears and let the VALUE COLUMN be 1000* DELTA of that row. for all consecutive rows of that ID, the VALUE is the VALUE of the row above * the DELTA of the current row.

I tried by getting all unique ID values:

```
a=stocks2.ID.unique()
a.tolist()
```

It works, unfortunately I do not really know how to iterate in the way I described. Any kind of help or tip would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it would be as follows. Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,5,3,3], 'delta':[0.3,0.5,0.2,2,4]}).assign(value=[2,5,4,2,3])
print(df)
   ID  delta   value
0   1    0.3     2
1   1    0.5     5
2   5    0.2     4
3   3    2.0     2
4   3    4.0     3
```

Fill `value` from the row above as:

```
df['value'] = df.shift(1).delta * df.shift(1).value
```

[`Groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the indices where the first `ID` appears:

```
w = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).nth(0).index.values
```

And compute the values for `value` using the indices in `w`:

```
df.loc[w,'value'] = df.loc[w,'delta'] * 1000
```

Which gives for this example:

```
 ID  delta   value
0   1    0.3   300.0
1   1    0.5     0.6
2   5    0.2   200.0
3   3    2.0  2000.0
4   3    4.0     4.0
```

Comment: First of all , thank you so much !!! Only the very last part I think I did not describe properly. the second row value.. the nth row value of the first ID is always the delta times the row value of value above .

Comment: Edited, let me know if it does what you want

Comment: The problem is the sequence I think. I want to start each ID with 1000*... and then each subsequent is based on the last one..So i would have to set the unique values first

Comment: In any case please remember to accept the answer so I know it helped

Comment: Thank you soooo much. If you know any place I maybe could read up on it. Highly appreciated

Comment: Not quite sure what to suggest, as it is a very specific problem. Some good pandas skills always help though, so you might want to start there. Happy coding!